# Airflow : need advices when running a lot of instances per task

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow

This is my 1st post on Stack and it is about Airflow. I need to implement a DAG which will :

1/ Download files from an API

2/ Upload them into Google Cloud Storage

3/ Insert them into BigQuery

The thing is that the step 1 involves about 170 accounts to be call. If any error is raised during the download, I want my DAG to automatically retry it from the abended step. Therefore I implemented a loop above my tasks such as :

```
dag = DAG('my_dag', default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS)

for account in accounts:

    t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='download_file_' + account['id'],
                 python_callable=download_files(account),
                 dag=my_dag)

    t2 = FileToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(task_id='upload_file_' + account['id'],
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id = 'gcs_my_conn',
                src = 'file_'  + account['id'] + '.json',
                bucket = 'my_bucket',
                dag=my_dag)

    t3 = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(task_id='insert_bq',
                bucket = 'my_bucket',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id = 'gcs_my_conn',
                bigquery_conn_id = 'bq_my_conn',
                src = 'file_'  + account['id'],
                destination_project_dataset_table = 'my-project:my-dataset.my-table',
                source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
                dag=my_dag)

    t2.set_upstream(t1)
    t3.set_upstream(t2)
```

So at UI level, I have about 170 instances of each task display. When I run the DAG manually, Airflow is just doing nothing as far as I can see. The DAG is don't init or queued any task instance. I guess this is due to the number of instances involve but I don't know how can I workaround this.

How should I manage so many task instances ?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Hey, AlexLng, what's your concurrency setting for a DAG, it sounds like you want to allow only 1 task running at a time.

Comment: Hi @Chengzhi , yes it is exactly what I'm looking for. I can not use parallelism for my API calls because I would be rejected by the provider. I just left the concurrency settings by default as it's using the SequentialExecutor (which is supposed to run one task instance at a time).

Comment: Hi Chengzhi, would you have some suggestion to provide ?

Comment: Hey, Alex, can you post how is your DAG default_arg looks like? The retries part you can handle by adding a argument retries in python operator.

Comment: Chengzhi, my DAG default_arg looks like this : 
`
    DEFAULT_ARGS = { 'owner': 'airflow', 'depends_on_past': False, 
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 25), 'email': ['myemail'], 
    'email_on_failure': False, 'email_on_retry': False, 'retries': 2, 'retry_delay': 
    datetime.timedelta(minutes=2) }
`
Could you please explain me what you're thinking about this retry argument ? With my current setup,the retry will start every task from the beginning and it will lead to duplicates in my BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running airflow currently? Are you sure the `airflow  scheduler` is running?

You can also run `airflow list_dags` to ensure the dag can be compiled. If you are running airflow using Celery you should take care that your dag shows up using `list_dags` on all nodes running airflow.

Comment: Hi Matthijs, yes the scheduler is running and the list_dags displays my dag correctly. I'm using the SequentialExecutor for now.

Answer (score 0):

Alex, it would be easier to post here, I saw you have DEFAULT_ARGS with retries which is at DAG level, you can also set up retries at task level as well. It is in BaseOperator, since all Operator will inherit the BaseOperator then you can use it, you can find more detail here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/python_operator.py and https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py#L1864, if you check BaseOperator in model, it has `retries` and `retry_delay`, you can do something like this:

```
t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='download_file_' + account['id'],
                 python_callable=download_files(account),
                 retries=3,
                 retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=300),
                 dag=my_dag)
```